# TLS error enrolling with Fabric CA Client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I prepared multi-organization with Fabric CA environment by following tutorial. This tutorial itself was worked with no problem.

> Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple
>   organizations)
>   https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html

In this environment, I'm trying Fabric CA client commands on both ca_peerOrg1 and host environment. I copied tls crt, public key and private key from crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/ and tried following command, but I got error "x509: certificate is valid for ca.org1.example.com, not localhost".

```
linux1@fabric:~$ fabric-ca-client enroll --caname ca-org1 --tls.certfiles ca.crt --tls.client.certfile Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem --tls.client.keyfile 0dbfd9d156b90331e6bc4a0529e07cb123f7de586935019499623062f182a8fa_sk -u https://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
2017/12/19 16:34:35 [INFO] User provided config file: /home/linux1/fabric-ca/clients/admin/fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
2017/12/19 16:34:35 [INFO] generating key: &{A:ecdsa S:256}
2017/12/19 16:34:35 [INFO] encoded CSR
2017/12/19 16:34:35 [INFO] TLS Enabled
Error: POST failure [Post https://localhost:7054/enroll: x509: certificate is valid for ca.org1.example.com, not localhost]; not sending
POST https://localhost:7054/enroll
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5wdw==
{"hosts":["fabric"],"certificate_request":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\nMIIBOzCB4wIBADBdMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEXMBUGA1UECBMOTm9ydGggQ2Fyb2xp\nbmExFDASBgNVBAoTC0h5cGVybGVkZ2VyMQ8wDQYDVQQLEwZGYWJyaWMxDjAMBgNV\nBAMTBWFkbWluMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEI8Y4aR/YxeyMXIQ3\nHGydrTLaoI+6tZ57ho1uv6gNonbFfftE7lrdsIbL8d8QLimztDjtqkg6rk612nso\nD66M9aAkMCIGCSqGSIb3DQEJDjEVMBMwEQYDVR0RBAowCIIGZmFicmljMAoGCCqG\nSM49BAMCA0cAMEQCIH9u2w9xO43Ba5rJ1SCKgtEFfokj1DKhg2cHjnbu8ucEAiBn\nwZKjjSbQage+ElofYbgagWpuCFz0t57Zwycz22M00w==\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n","profile":"","crl_override":"","label":"","CAName":"ca-org1"}
linux1@fabric:~$
```

How can I avoid this error ? When I'm looking at the tutorial, I realized that composer connection profile has configuration like "hostnameOverride": "ca.org1.example.com". I guess I need to do same kind for fabric-ca-client.

Comment: I had bit progress. I specified "ca.org1.example.com" instead of "localhost" for CA server name, and I got another error "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority".

Comment: Looks like your certificate of the CA wasn't signed by ca.crt from the commandline.

Comment: I suggest you do: 
openssl x509 -in $f -text -noout
when $f is the certificate file, for both of the CA certificate and the fabric-CA's TLS certificate, and post them here.

Comment: Yacovm, Thank you for your suggestion. I realized that I was using wrong CA certificate. I used fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem and everything worked !

Comment: Seems you need to specify `--csr.hosts ca.org1.example.com` or something similar.

Comment: @MaxPeng How we can add --csr.hosts ca.org1.example.com to the certificate enroll request using fabric node sdk.

Comment: @ArunSalaria Can you check the code of fabric node sdk at here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.4/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClient.js#L410 and fabric ca https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/release-1.4/api/client.go#L51 and https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/73021725f9fcdfcbf7bad0d983e55788871d571b/lib/client.go#L227